# Effective way to remove trapped lint inside blower wheel? Maytag mgd8630hw0

Tags: cleaning, dryer, appliances

I have a less than year old maytag mgd8630hw0 gas dryer. The dryer is on the second floor and vents through the roof.

About 3 months ago the dryer started making a loud banging noise so we call the repair company. The guy came out, took everything apart and then cleaned out the lint stuck in the blower wheel with a set of pliers (might have the wrong part name - I am talking about the area under the lint screen and before the rea exhaust). He said if I used a lint brush and regularly vacuumed I should be able to keep it under control (it would be great to install a automated suction blower in the piping, but that is a big undertaking since I don't have easy electrical access in the attic currently).

In any event, last week the dryer started really pounding (it was also a large load), afterwards I did everything I could to try to clean the dryer, I even got behind it and tried vacuuming out from the back...

The problem is that it's very hard to actually get into the area where all the lint is stuck. It's really in there, I tried both vacuuming and blowing. I am hesitant to try to take everything apart myself to manually get in their with pliers, it also seems crazy to have to do every 2-3 months in order to keep this area free of excess lint leading to noise and problems.

I've run the dryer since, and it makes less noise, but I know there is still a lot of lint stuck in there because I have one of those endoscope cameras and I was able to snake in to take photos (below).

I saw in [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6937/how-can-i-access-the-lint-duct-assembly-of-a-maytag-centennial-dryer/14973#14973) that the OP removed his outlet grill and was able to get in there a bit better. When I tried this, I got all the screws out but it still felt like something was wedged and I was worried I might pull to hard and snap the plastic.

---

tl;dr is there any secret way or special tool that I can use to get into this area? Or it it normal to have some build up of lint in this area - if so how much is acceptable?

I've tried a [flexible grabber](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MPX5RGQ), brushes, vacuums, blowing, etc. I either can't reach it or can't maneuver it enough to really get much of anything for the amount of effort and time I put in. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to access from the back because there is a small opening and a turn at the end reaching in from the back.

Where I am trying to clean/access:

[image]

Photos of the lint trapped inside:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, it looks like these fins have a lot of lint packed into sheets so I don't think any amount of suction or blowing is going to help unless I could really find a way to get in there or seal it off.

Comment: According to the user manual the inside should only have to be cleaned every two years.   Are sure there's not something else going wrong if you already need to do it after 3 months?

Comment: The exhaust goes out vertical through the roof which is not as good as if it just went out the side of the house. However, if it were a an issue of insufficient pressure/suction then I would have thought blasting it with a small shop vac on vaccuum or blowing would help. The repair man told me he has at least 2 calls a day where the problem turned out to be the same thing with lint. He said these newer models are good, but he sees this often.

Comment: Odd design. I would think that it shouldn't be blown outside either considering how much micro plastics is already in the environment, but I guess that's not exactly illegal. Good luck with the fix!

Comment: Where do you get "that is a big undertaking since I don't have easy electrical access in the attic…", please?

At worst, why would it be difficult to run an extension cable from a socket anywhere in the building?

Answer (score 1):

Make a long hook from a metal coat hanger and scrape **gently** , it looks like it will peel off easily.

Something I have done often, in fact I have several hooks made like that.

Comment: aw, of course - i was racking my head trying to figure out how i could build something flexible but rigid enough. It still hard to see into this area, but I will try taping the scope on if ned be.

Answer (score 0):

Use car detailing vacuum attachments to fit into the space. They come in a varity of shapes and sizes to fit into the deep and narrow spaces in a car such as the air vent louvers / ducts. They will have no problem reaching that space. As a bonus, you will likely find a LOT of other uses for them such as cleaning your computer case.

[image]

Comment: Will these go on an angle? I've tried using other attachments and hoses that can fit in the space, but they just don't suck enough.

Comment: Yes, it would be the item in the picture, second row from the bottom on the right. That wide area is a corrugated section that is bendable. The size of the solid part is like a large straw and it can fit into small areas. The item on the bottom row right can fit the end, it is a mini brush